# Multi Line Field Return All Lines of Data with CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am querying SharePoint and am pulling data from a multi-line text field. My issue is that only the most recent line is pulled from the multi-line entry.

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in listItemCollection)
{
  Console.WriteLine(listItem[”mtInfo”];
}
```

> I changed my syntax to the below and I get a debug **error of
>   Ststem.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object type System.String to type Sharepoint.client.fieldmultilinetext**

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in listItemCollection)
{
  FieldMultiLineText multi = (FieldMultiLineText)listItem[“mtInfo”];
  String description = String.Empty;
  If (multi != null)
    description = multi.ToString();
  Console.WriteLine(description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have enabled 'Append text to existing text" for your multiple lines of text field.

By default, we can get the “Append Changes to Existing Text” newest version value from a multiple line text field using JavaScript Client Object Model. There is no straight way can get the versions of the Multi-line text column in Client Object Model.

As a workaround, we can use the [Lists.GetVersionCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.getversioncollection(v=office.15).aspx) Method of the List.asmx web service instead.

Refer to:

[SharePoint web services: read version history for column changes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pinch-perfect/2016/06/04/sharepoint-web-services-read-version-history-for-column-changes/)

[How to get list item field versions data in SharePoint Online](https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/how-get-list-item-field-versions-data-sharepoint-online)

Comment: hey @JoannaW_MSFT, the asmx services are [deprecated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/choose-the-right-api-set-in-sharepoint#DeprecatedAPIs) , the developers should not be using them.

Comment: I am wanting to use a Windows form to return this data. Is it possible to use the JQuery you link to with a Windows form?